# Error while installing web3@1.0.0-beta.26 on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, ethereum, web3js

I am getting the following error while installing web3@1.0.0-beta.26 on Windows 10.

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for web3-core@1.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'web3-eth'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tanuj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-18T05_50_02_703Z-debug.log
```

I have already successfully run

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a stable web3 version and see if, despite some errors on windows, you have in your project the folder `node_modules` and the file `package-lock.json`

It should work despite the errors